# code coverage not getting upload in Sonar Qube

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, angular-unit-test

I have coverage folder in Angular 4 project, i have to upload all ts code issue, code coverage to sonarQube. Except code coverage everything works fine. following is my sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=STUDENT-FORM
sonar.projectName=STUDENT-FORM
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=e41e6e5cdc17b412e76d0c3c6a6cca77e5517910
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts
sonar.inclusions=src/**/*
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=tslint.json
sonar.ts.lcov.reportpath=coverage/lcov.info
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding following property solved my problem
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info